# Doing an event while a finger is on the same spot of the screen? Libgdx

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

How can I poll an event for a single finger all at once? To be more specific basically I need to find out when a person is touching the screen but they need to stay in the same spot the whole time and this needs to be implemented with multitouch so if they keep any of there fingers in the same spot for lets say 500ms then I can have an action happen. All code that I have tried hasn't work and I am mostly annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.multitouch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MultiTouch extends Activity {
    protected LinearLayout sq1;
    protected LinearLayout sq2;
    protected LinearLayout sq3;
    protected LinearLayout sq4;

    protected String sqText = new String();
    protected String sq1Text = new String();
    protected String sq2Text = new String();
    protected String sq3Text = new String();

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setViews();
        handler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 5000);
    }

    private final Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do whatever you want to change here, like:
            updateTextField();
        }
    };

    private void updateTextField() {
        TextView view1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.logView);
        TextView view2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.logView1);
        TextView view3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.logView2);
        TextView view4 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.logView3);


        //view1.append(sqText + "\n");
        view1.setText(sqText);
        view2.setText(sq1Text);
        view3.setText(sq2Text);
        view4.setText(sq3Text);

        handler.post(mUpdateUITimerTask);
    }

    private void setViews() {
         sq1 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.square1);
         sq2 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.square2);
         sq3 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.square3);
         sq4 = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.square4);

         sq1.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
         sq2.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
         sq3.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
         sq4.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());        
    }

    private class TouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

             if(event.getPointerCount()>2) {
                sq1Text = "GOT THREE POINTERS!!";
                sq2Text = "GOT THREE POINTERS!!";
                sq3Text = "GOT THREE POINTERS!!";
                sqText = "GOT THREE POINTERS!!";
             }

             if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText = "Square 1 Pressed::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()); 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text = "Square 2 Pressed::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()); 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text = "Square 3 Pressed::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()); 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text =  "Square 4 Pressed::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()); 
                   break;
                }
             }  else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ||
                        event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                 switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText = "Square 1 Pointer Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text =  "Square 2 Pointer Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text =  "Square 3 Pointer Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text =  "Square 4 Pointer Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                }
             } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN) {
                 switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText = "Square 1 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text =  "Square 2 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text =  "Square 3 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text = "Square 4 Pointer1Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                }
             } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN) {
                 switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText = "Square 1 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text =  "Square 2 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text =  "Square 3 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text =  "Square 4 Pointer2Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                }
             } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN) {
                 switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText =  "Square 1 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text =  "Square 2 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text =  "Square 3 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text = "Square 4 Pointer3Down::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                }
             } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                 switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText = "Square 1 UP::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text =  "Square 2 UP::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text =  "Square 3 UP::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text =  "Square 4 UP::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                }
             } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                 switch(v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.square1:
                       sqText = "Square 1 MOVE::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square2:
                       sq1Text =  "Square 2 MOVE::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square3:
                       sq2Text =  "Square 3 MOVE::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                   case R.id.square4:
                       sq3Text =  "Square 4 MOVE::Pointer count = " + String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()) + "\n"; 
                   break;
                }
             }


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainLay" >

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:padding="10dip">


        <TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:padding="10dip">
            <LinearLayout android:background="#FFFF00" android:id="@+id/square1" android:padding="10px" android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="125px"/>
            <LinearLayout android:background="#FF00FF" android:id="@+id/square2" android:padding="10px" android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="125px"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:padding="10dip">
            <LinearLayout android:background="#00FFFF" android:id="@+id/square3" android:padding="10px" android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="125px"/>
            <LinearLayout android:background="#eeeeee" android:id="@+id/square4" android:padding="10px" android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="125px"/>
        </TableRow>     


          <TextView android:id="@+id/logView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/logView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/logView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          <TextView android:id="@+id/logView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question I am working with libgdx not the android sdk.